# hibernate CriteriaBuilder orderBy null ordering

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my hibernate project, all the CriteriaBuilder query with orderBy column has a *nulls last* getting added automatically. I am using Oracle db. For example:

```
order by creation_date desc nulls last
```

Is there a way to change this behavior? What I want is

```
order by creation_date desc
```

I even tried column with NOT Null constraint but not seeing any difference.

Comment: The issue was with my project. Some initialization code was programmatically adding DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING property with the value of last.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with my project. Some initialization code was programmatically adding DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING property with the value of last.